# Parsing on node js with cheerio (JQuery API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, request, cheerio

I'm trying to scrap site.

I want to scrap version (2.5.1), but I don't know how to scrap only version without `href="` and `<a title=`.

```html
<div class="box-title">All Versions</div>

<div class="row" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%;">
    <table class="striped" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <tbody>
            <tr><td><a title="download Ultimate Ninja Blazing 2.5.1 apk " onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'download_ver', 'com.bandainamcoent.narutoblazingna_2018-05-08.apk');" href="/download-app/com.bandainamcoent.narutoblazingna/4_com.bandainamcoent.narutoblazingna_2018-05-08.apk/">2.5.1</a></td><td>May 8, 2018</td></tr>
            <tr><td><a title="download Ultimate Ninja Blazing 2.5.0 apk " onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'download_ver', 'com.bandainamcoent.narutoblazingna_2018-04-30.apk');" href="/download-app/com.bandainamcoent.narutoblazingna/5_com.bandainamcoent.narutoblazingna_2018-04-30.apk/">2.5.0</a></td><td>April 30, 2018</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Also i want to know how to get all `</tr><tr>` from site page for my cheerio

result should looks like on this sample :)

```
{ version: '2.5.1' },
{ version: '2.5.0' }
```

My parse code :

```
const row = $('.row');
const version = row.info('tr').find('td').eq(1);

console.log(row);
console.log(version);

const fields = {
    row,
    version
};
```

Thanks everybody for help : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is an working example**

I hope that this is what you wanted.

```js
const row = $('.row');
const version = [];

row.find('tr').each(function (i, e) {
  version.push({"version": $(this).find("td a[title^='download']").text()});
});

console.log(version);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box-title">All Versions</div>

<div class="row" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%;">
  <table class="striped" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a title="download Ultimate Ninja Blazing 2.5.1 apk " onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'download_ver', 'com.bandainamcoent.narutoblazingna_2018-05-08.apk');" href="/download-app/com.bandainamcoent.narutoblazingna/4_com.bandainamcoent.narutoblazingna_2018-05-08.apk/">2.5.1</a></td>
        <td>May 8, 2018</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a title="download Ultimate Ninja Blazing 2.5.0 apk " onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'download_ver', 'com.bandainamcoent.narutoblazingna_2018-04-30.apk');" href="/download-app/com.bandainamcoent.narutoblazingna/5_com.bandainamcoent.narutoblazingna_2018-04-30.apk/">2.5.0</a></td>
        <td>April 30, 2018</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Bro ! it's work ! : ) you're really save me )